# Using JavaScript labels without break and continue statements

Tags: javascript

In JavaScipt, labels are usually used with `break` and `continue` statements for interrupting execution of code and so on... But, is it a good idea to use labels for creating local variables that are available only inside these labels and for separating some piece code from another? Like this:

```
label: {
    let someVariable = "someValue";
    let someVariable1 = "someValue1";
    
    //someCode...
};
```

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with labels. You're just using a block-statement with a redundant label. Removing the label has the exact same result.

Comment: "*is it a good idea to use labels*" basically 100% of the time the answer is "no". There *are* cases where labels are useful but it's statistically insignificant percentage, so I've rounded up for convenience. "*for creating local variables that are available only inside these labels*" you want a code block. That's it.

Comment: Ok, I've understood. Thanks for answer.